# Any sample project use Directshow.net Library to capture video and save into .avi video file?

Tags: .net, streaming, video-capture

Any sample project use Directshow.net Library to capture video and save into .avi video file?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx

Comment: it use DShwoNET, but it's a solution